# Database design. And get last modified time with each column in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

My database/table each endpoint/scope  have multiple table,
e.g user:  user, user_information, user_role ...
I was wondering should I separate table like below, or not?

This is my first time to build a product not like before just make some onetime  work small website. and this it might add more feature in future version.

I'm not sure about is this overdesign?  Does separate table like this any benefit in the future ??
and cons I know is use more table join, and more difficult to me to maintain build the query.

any suggestion, share experience will be really appreciate.

For now I only can imagine I might want to know each column last modified time?

So if I want to know each column last modified time, is there any original build method in PostgreSQL? or I have to add for each column like `email_last_modified_date`, `username_last_modified_date` ...

endpoint/scope user

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "create_date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "last_modified_by_user_id" integer,
    "status" integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user_information"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "create_date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "last_modified_by_user_id" integer,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "username" varchar(50),
    "password" varchar NOT NULL,
    "first_name" varchar(50),
    "last_name" varchar(50),
    "website" varchar,
    "description" varchar,
    "birth_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "country" varchar(50),
    "gender" integer,
    "file_type" integer,
    "file_name" varchar(50),
    "file_extension" varchar(50),
    "file_portrait" boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "user" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user_role"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "create_date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "last_modified_by_user_id" integer,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "role" integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "user" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  );
```

merge table ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "create_date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "last_modified_by_user_id" integer,
    "status" integer NOT NULL,

    "information_last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "information_last_modified_by_user_id" integer,
     .... user_information 

    "role_last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone,
    "role_last_modified_by_user_id" integer,
    ... user_role
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table for each entity (where an entity is something significant to the business that needs to be identified uniquely) and for each many-to-many relationship. So user, role, userrole each get a table. There's no value making a separation between user and user information, you only introduce another join.

If you're thinking you want an optimal way to handle joins from user to role without loading the user information: if you put indexes on your tables many queries may be able to use only the index and will not have to read the table unless there's some specific data required. No need to make a separate user information table.

What you're doing with the merged example is not clear to me, it seems like an extreme case of denormalization.

If you want to track changes you might look up event-sourcing, which would provide a way to keep a full history of changes. See http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html for an introduction. Short of that you could keep history for specific entities you're concerned about tracking changes for.
.

Comment: Thanks for reply!  what is event-sourcing? do you mean this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589792.aspx?

Comment: @user1775888: yes same thing.

Comment: I use PostgreSQL with nodejs,  and I found this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventstore ,   does event sourcing mean, it trigger on postgresql event, but I still need to store data on database?

Comment: if right now I have no need in this version, is it easy to add in the future(lot data in database)?  If so I might just use above schema, and next if use event sourcing , then remove column in table.

Comment: Event-sourcing isn't something you bolt on as an afterthought